# Unknown Error Cause While Debugging WPF - 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SkiaSharp.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, skiasharp

I am incredibly new to C# (my knowledge comes exclusively from YouTube tutorials), so please keep this in mind when viewing my novice code! I apologize in advance.
I am trying to develop a WPF desktop application using VS2022. Without going into extensive detail, the application needs to be capable of loading and displaying SVG files, as well as storing the path data. For this, I am using the SkiaSharp and Skia.Svg nuget packages.
As in the title, when the program tries to run the 'draw' function, it gives the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SkiaSharp.dll
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

The following are how I initialized the canvas, as well as the 'draw' function itself:

canvas:

```
SKCanvas canvas;

        public void CreateCanvas()
        {

            SKImageInfo info = new SKImageInfo(1920, 1080);
            SKSurface surface = SKSurface.Create(info);
            canvas = surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear(SKColors.Empty);

        }
        
        //not actually sure if this is an initializer oop...
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            CreateCanvas();

        }
```

draw function:

```
        private void draw(string path, SKCanvas canvas)
        {

            var svg = new SKSvg();

            svg.Load(path);

            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);

        }
```

The "path" string is simply the filepath for the desired svg. The one I've been feeding it for debug purposes is on my desktop, and I am running VS as admin. Again, I'm new to this, so I'm not sure where the error lies or what really causes it. Seeking help in determining the root cause!

Comment: Lots of SVG libraries around, try another one.

Comment: Are there any you recommend?